# How to tell my java exe to read a ini file in same folder?

Tags: java, launch4j

I have a jar that I run this from command line

```
java -jar -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties AddNUmbers-1.0.jar "3" "5"
```

I changed jar to an exe using [launch4j-Maven-Plugin](https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin) like this **AddNumbers.exe** . now the command line looks like this

```
AddNumbers "3" "5"
```

But I dont have -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties in there and I lost ability to log things. Saw an example out which was using ini to pass that in but not sure how to tell my exe to look for it.

Anyone ran into similar thing and have got by it in past of having exe read ini file that has JVM arguments needed at runtime

Comment: Could you create your own log file?

Comment: I do have the capability but it needs to read logging.properties file at run time

Comment: If you wrote the code, can't you set it to read logging.properites when the program start running?

Comment: just figured out how to set that when running it as exe .since we cant set it directly when it is an exe since there is no java command being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going thorough documentation on launch4j website I found it we want to pass JVM arguments at runtime we need to create file with same name and ".l4j.ini" extension in same folder as the exe.

So create a file with AddNumbers.l4j.ini and in it putting

```
 -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties
```

resolved my situation

Comment: Did you make any changes in your pom.xml for the plugin to tell the exe to look at the ini file or did it automatically read the ini file.